# Phalcon: save reference to new record in one transaction

Tags: orm, save, phalcon, phalcon-orm

Im trying to save a reference to a new object in a single transaction [as shown here in the documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/model-transactions.html) under 'implicit transactions':

I am creating two new objects of the same class, one is then referencing the other. From the documentation, the save should be performed on TreeNodeA when TreeNodeB is saved and the ID will be passed to `TreeNodeB->parent_tree_node_id`

This doesnt seem to be working, and it still being passed as an object as Im getting the error on the save function:

```
Object of class TreeNodes could not be converted to string
```

I've tried writing a saveTreeParentNodeId function in the model and also setting it using the alias, but neither seem to work.

```
    $treeNode = new TreeNodes();
    $treeNode->setConnectionService(Registry::setConnection(MyModel::MAIN_DB));
    $parentNode = $treeNode->findFirst();

    $treeNodeA = new TreeNodes();
    $treeNodeA->tree_id = $parentNode->tree_id;
    $treeNodeA->tree_parent_node_id = $parentNode;
    $treeNodeA->tree_level_id = 2;
    $treeNodeA->node_desc = "Test Node A";

    $treeNodeB = new TreeNodes();
    $treeNodeB->tree_id = $parentNode->tree_id;
    $treeNodeB->tree_parent_node_id = $treeNodeA;
    $treeNodeB->tree_level_id = 3;
    $treeNodeB->tree_desc = "Test Node B";
    $treeNodeB->save();
```

The model:

```
class TreeNodes extends MyModel
{
    public $node_id;
    public $tree_id;
    public $tree_parent_node_id;
    public $tree_level_id;
    public $node_desc;

    public function getSource()
    {
        return "TreeNodes";
    }

    public function setTreeParentNodeId(TreeNodes $parentNode){
        $this->tree_parent_node_id = $parentNode->node_id;
    }

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->belongsTo(
            'tree_id',
            'Organisations',
            'TreeID',
            array(
                'alias' => 'organisation',
                'reusable' => true
            )
        );

        $this->hasOne(
            'tree_id',
            'TreeType',
            'tree_id',
            array(
                'alias' => 'type',
                'reusable' => true
            )
        );

        $this->hasOne(
            'tree_parent_node_id',
            'TreeNodes',
            'node_id',
            array(
                'alias' => 'parentNode'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

By updating the model to use belongsTo, Phalcon recognises the parentNode.

```
    $this->belongsTo(
        'tree_parent_node_id',
        'TreeNodes',
        'node_id',
        array(
            'alias' => 'parentNode'
        )
    );
```

This enables $treeNodeA to save implicitly when $treeNodeB is saved.

```
    $treeNodeA->parentNode = $parentNode;
```

Unfortunately, $treeNodeB with a reference to $treeNodeA as the parentNode is NOT saved. No error message is returned either, just 'true'.

Comment: I updated my answer! In your `belongsTo`, you switched your `field` with the  `referenced field` ( `tree_parent_node_id` with `node_id` )

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation example you linked, they assign the `$robotPart` object to `$robot->robotPart`. `robotPart` refers to the linked RobotPart object and not to the ID ( to which you are trying to assign your object )

```
$treeNodeB = new TreeNodes();
$treeNodeB->tree_id = $parentNode->tree_id;
// $treeNodeB->tree_parent_node_id = $treeNodeA;
$treeNodeB->parentNode = $treeNodeA;
$treeNodeB->save();
```

You should use `parentNode` here because this is the name you gave to your relationship via `hasOne`.

I haven't tested this myself, but by following the documentation's logic, this should push you in the right direction.

---

Alter you model relationships so you have both sides of the relation

```
// let Phalcon know that "tree_parent_node_id" is a reference to "node_id"
$this->hasOne(
    'tree_parent_node_id', // your column
    'TreeNodes', // referenced table
    'node_id', // referenced table column
    array(
        'alias'      => 'parentNode',
        'foreignKey' => true
    )
);

// let Phalcon know that "node_id" is being referenced as a FK in "TreeNodes"
$this->belongsTo(
    'node_id', // PK
    'TreeNodes', // referenced table
    'tree_parent_node_id', // referenced table column
    array('foreignKey' => ['message' => 'FK constraint error between node_id and tree_parent_node_id'])
);
```

Comment: Timothy to the rescue again! I had given this a try already. Ive managed to get the errors from it now:  `protected $_message => string(31) "tree_parent_node_id is required"`. Its a shame they dont show the models and aliases theyve created for Robot and RobotPart

Comment: I see that you haven't specifically told Phalcon that your relation with `parentNode` is connected via a "foreign key", try adding `'foreignKey'=> true` in the same array as `'alias' => 'parentNode'`

Comment: Updated the question and tried using foreign key flag. It does change the behaviour, now the message `Value of field "tree_parent_node_id" does not exist on referenced table` when trying to save $testNodeA

Comment: Now you are confusing `belongsTo` with `hasOne`

Comment: Good thinking. Im playing around with those now. The configuration youve given me there always gives me the error 'FK constraint error between node_id and tree_parent_node_id'. Im playing around with it to see if I can get the right settings

Comment: Have you also altered your first implicit transaction `$treeNodeA->tree_parent_node_id = $parentNode;` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115299/discussion-between-timothy-and-jackalopezero).